# cURL error 28 - Connection timed out after x milliseconds

Tags: php, curl

Yep. I know there is some alike questions about this err but i was read all of this and it not resolve my problem so:

My php code:

```
    $url = 'example.domain.com/path/file.php'
    $string = 'param=5';

    $ch = curl_init();

    // CURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($string)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);

    return curl_exec($ch);
```

I check errors this way:

```
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);

 if($curl_errno > 0) {
   echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
 }
```

`$curl_errorno` is 28 and
`curl_error` is Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Please help or get some clue what I can check.

**from localhost or other server is it also working (curl or file_get_content)... is there any hint?**

- from local machine i get cURL ok response via php ~4sec
- from server (host server) shell i get error 7 failed to connect to example.domain.com port 80: connection timed out
- if in php try `file_get_contents` (from host server) - no response
- URL - is accessible from browser (direct php file)
- If i create `ajax` request - response is ok
- If i trying add to url http or https - always same error
- if i trying set limit to 30 sec. same result

Comment: you should be setting CURL_POST to 1 like this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` This may not be the cause of problem but to post you need to do this. Oh and can you provide link to php file you are trying to do this with?

Comment: The connection seems to just get stuck so it times out after 10 seconds.

Comment: maximum time the request is allowed to take is now set to 10 - normal request more then sufficient; what happens if you increate `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to 20? Same results?

Comment: @daan.desmedt yes

Comment: how i can get it? i mean so yes

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you try to say. Running a `curl` from a personal cloud server (to the url you pasted above)... Gets the correct response : `a` .... Seems to work perfect. Have a look if any proxy is blocking your `curl` request

Comment: The only wrong part in your code I see is the missing `;` at the end of `$url = 'example.domain.com/path/file.php'`

Comment: Not possible anymore. Comments are only editable for 5mins. I've removed my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to increase CURLOPT_TIMEOUT or remove timeout of cURL execution at all

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem, this is because the API you are trying to send the request does not accept the sending of many products at the same time. Then you need to put the **PHP sleep function**, so between each sent line a range is defined. Add `sleep(seconds of interval);` in your code.

Comment: how I can add sleep() function? within curl?